# kdb: How to read the data of the specified column name from the flat table

Tags: file, field, kdb, bin

Suppose I have a table t locally, stored in the path `d:/t, the table has two columns, the form is as follows:

```
a b   
------
0 "ab"
1 "bc"
2 "cd"
```

I use “set” to save locally.

```
t:([]a:til 3;b:("ab";"bc";"cd"))
`:d:/t set data
```

My question is: How can I read only column b from the binary file "d:/t".
The expected result is as follows:

```
b   
----
"ab"
"bc"
"cd"
```

It seems that the function "get" can only get all the data, and cannot read the specified column.what should I do?
Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Thomas said you can't load single columns from a binary file without loading the whole contents of that file.

If your flat file is small enough however, and you'd rather not splay it, then you can still specify specific columns when querying the table - as if you had access to those columns individually:

```
q)t:([]a:til 3;b:("ab";"bc";"cd"))
q)`:test set t
q)select b from `:test
b
----
"ab"
"bc"
"cd"
```

Don't be fooled, this is effectively the same operation as `` select b from get`:t ``, i.e. we still have to load the whole flat file for the duration of the query. But this avoids having to litter your code with `get`'s

Answer (score 3):

Flat files cannot index at depth - the whole file will be read.

Splayed tables store each column as a file for indexing speed:

https://code.kx.com/q/kb/splayed-tables/

Anymap files also provide speed when indexing at depth:

https://code.kx.com/q/releases/ChangesIn3.6/#anymap

```
q)t:flip (`$"t_",/:string til 50)!{1000000?100.0} each til 50
q)`:flat set t
q)`:splay/ set t
q)`:anymap 1: t
```

```
q)\ts select t_10 from `:flat
891 423626128
q)\ts select t_10 from `:splay
2 4196064
q)\ts select t_10 from `:anymap
0 4195424
```

Answer (score 1):

When saving a table as a single binary file then the entire contents must be loaded, there is no way to load an individual column only.

If you want to load a single column only then you will need to take a slightly different approach and splay the table to disk, so that all the columnns exist as separate files.

You can do this by placing a trailing `/` at the end of the filepath to indicate you are saving to a directory.

```
`:d:/t/ set data
```

You can then read each corresponding column separately, although it will be returned as a list.

```
get`:d:/t/b
"ab"
"bc"
"cd"
```

Note if there are any symbol columns then the table will need enumerated with `.Q.en`.